# Closed post seconds after posting?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How do I prevent partial text from appearing at the bottom of a button added at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361669/how-do-i-prevent-partial-text-from-appearing-at-the-bottom-of-a-button-added-at)

I posted this question and it was closed literally seconds after I posted it. It had a pic attached and details describing the question about an issue that is illustrated by the pic. If the I thought code was necessary to illustrate the intent I would have added it.

What do I need to do to get my question reopened?  I need some advice, please.

Comment: "perhaps never".... I feel like whatever message you had also had a "please read the help center for more details". How much did you read? Cause as far as I remember the help center is clear this isn't permanent...

Comment: I mean sure, [600 seconds](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+minutes+to+seconds) for [your post to be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59361669/timeline) *is* literally seconds after it's posted...but maybe not on the same order of magnitude you're thinking or projecting...

Comment: Also, your question when you opened it is "I tried this. didn't work, how do I do this?". Then here you ask *What in the world is this site for?*. Well the site is for "the future visitor having the same issue as you". The way your original question was phrased, I can't see it helping anyone else but you. Also, you want feedback... there's a big closure banner giving you feedback. What good would a comment reiterating the same do? (also you had a comment saying *You should show how you created this(these) button(s). Post code, not pictures* posted 10 minutes **before** closure. It didn't help)

Comment: Just an FYI - this question doesn't deserve to closed as a dupe. It's asking a specific question about a specific circumstance and the dupes are referencing more generic advice and guidance which would not be of value to the OP.

Comment: @Makoto Looks like an exact duplicate to me. Note that I changed the dupe target from what gnat had originally suggested, since I agree it was not a duplicate of *that*. This question is asking why their question got closed so quickly, without a comment or giving them a chance to improve it. That’s exactly what the duplicates address.

Comment: @CodyGray:  Yes, but I have to wonder if the purpose of the duplicate closure was more to answer the letter of the question rather than the spirit of the question.  Letter of the question - sure, no complaints.  Spirit of the question - it's obvious that the OP is looking for some support on their specific circumstance, and this is not something that a duplicate can even begin to touch upon without it being too hand-wavy.

Comment: I deal primarily in letters, @Makoto, although I have on occasion been accused of being “spirited”. If you see a question here that is being implicitly asked, rather than what is implicitly asked, you might consider editing.

Comment: Sure, @CodyGray.  I've made an edit to the question.  Do let me know if I've taken out *too* much...

Comment: @Makoto You had me at “pontificate”

Answer (score 12):

The objective of the closure was to get you to improve the question.  Notably, [this is what your first draft was.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59361669/1)

> I have tried setting text align values...no good.In the attached pic, t looks like the text is trying to tile. [button pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLg72.png)

I mean, on a *good* day, that's automatic close bait right there.  All you've provided was a *picture* of your problem instead of anything that someone could search or pull into their own IDE.

You've since improved it by adding code.  I won't say for certain if that's a definitive improvement making it worthy of reopening *now*, but it's a step in the right direction.